# Colloquially, does the term "redhead" apply specifically to a person with naturally red hair?

Tags: meaning, american-english, colloquialisms

My husband and I were discussing this yesterday, and I was hoping y'all would give us an "official" answer.  :)

We both believe that for a person to be accurately described as a ***"redhead"***, they must have naturally red hair (or, at least, hair that *appears* naturally red), and possibly even the pale skin and/or freckles that stereotypically accompany it.

But we *firmly* agree that people with hair dyed unnaturally fire-engine red or any other shade obviously not apparent in the spectrum of natural hair colors are **not** redheads.

The dictionary definition, however, appears not to discriminate:

> red·head  (rĕd′hĕd′)
>   n.
>   1. A person with red hair.

What say you?  Does the term ***"redhead"*** apply only to people with naturally red hair? Or perhaps it extends to those who have hair dyed a *natural* shade of red?  Or would you say that it applies to ***all*** shades of red, natural or otherwise?

Comment: I belatedly realize that this could be construed as looking for opinion, but I am particularly hoping for answers related to common usage.

Comment: What about 'blond'? Are people who die their hair blond considered blond? (Just for comparison; the situations don't have to be the same.)

Comment: @Mitch  That was actually part of our discussion as well, but there are terms that apply to people with obviously dyed blond hair *(bleach blond, bottle blond)*... and I'm not sure there is a shade of blond that is so shockingly unnatural as the fire-engine red color.

Comment: 'platinum blond' is the extreme, though, similar to redheadedness, there are individuals that have that unnatural shade naturally

Comment: By 'fire engine red' I mean [this color](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/88/4b/1d/884b1db488def76220ae2553951cd038.jpg), which - to the best of my knowledge - does not appear naturally in human hair color.

Comment: How come there are no such word as *blackhead*, *blondhead*, or *brownhead*. There has to be a reason.

Comment: @Rathony There's no designer of a language Like English or Chinese, it just happens. And people fill gaps logically or not sometimes, and sometimes leave them unfilled. The reason you look for may be 'it just happened that way' or 'Uncle Phil was weird, we all just copied him though'

Comment: @Mitch That Uncle Phil, what a trendsetter!

Comment: Holly, this may very well be a philosophical question (as opposed to linguistic) or cultural (maybe if they always wear a bright red wig, people call them red-head anyway).

Comment: Wait, are you coming here after having a discussion with someone where you _agree_? No bets about who is right? No winner's perogative?

Comment: @Mitch  You may be right.  Perhaps I should delete it.

Comment: @Mitch  Yes, that's about the size of it.  We wondered if others would agree with us.

Comment: @Mitch Exactly. Red hair is one of the least common hair colors, maybe neck and neck with natural white color. Who cares if he/she dyed it or what? They just stand out and they are called redhead.

Comment: @HollyK As Mitch pointed out, Uncle Phil didn't care about this specific hair color. How many words are there to describe a blond hair or a certain race? Not many for red hair. There has to be a reason why.

Comment: So culturally, one says "That person is a redhead" when looking at their head and noticing that it is of that shade. Then someone might look closer and say 'Oh, that's a wig' or 'Oh that's so obviosuly a dye job'. Then one would say 'Then they're not a true redhead' And you probably wouldn't say 'That person is a redhead anymore'. But for bleach blond, you might still say 'They are blond, but not naturally'. So 'redhead' is somehow an adjective of essence, but 'blond' can just be the color however it happened. That's my opinion. A dictionary most likely won't get into such nuances.

Comment: @Rathony the reason _could_ be that red hair is rare. But then there are all sorts of words for rare things. There are languages ([Piraha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirah%C3%A3_language) that presumably don't have adjectives for colors, so that eg red is really 'blood-colored'. But English (and many languages) is deficient in a similar way for scents ('musty' is smells like 'must' (a mold)).

Comment: Suppose that as a child you had red hair, pale skin, and freckles, but then you dyed your hair black.  Are you still a redhead?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no great respecter of dictionaries, but you're right: the dictionary does not discriminate. Anybody having red hair, no matter how the hue was acquired, is a redhead, by *definition*. Presumably this is true, at least transfiguratively, of somebody whose hair is colored by blood after a serious wound, and of somebody whose hair is so colored by a mere trick of the light.

Yet the notion that 'redhead' often *connotes* (as opposed to *denotes*) a genetically marked set of people is accurate. As one of those people, I can swear to it. In terms of evidence, I'll offer these, briefly:

> 1784   T. Holcroft Noble Peasant i. i. 7   Zounds, Clym, hast no religion?—Dost not know that these Red-heads, these Carroty-poles, are Pagans?
>   ...
>   1893   K. Kohler in J. H. Barrows World's Parl. Relig. I. 366   You see man divided into groups of blackheads (the race of Ham) and redheads (Adam).
>   ...
>   1998   Stornoway Gaz. 31 Dec. 8/5   Once a redhead always a redhead—you do not forgo membership if your red hair turns silver or even if you go bald.

[From "redhead, n. and adj.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/160309?redirectedFrom=redhead (accessed October 05, 2015).]

I refer you especially to the 1998 quote, and remark that while I was once compared to a "frayed copper wire", that is no longer a viable comparison (at least with reference to my outward appearance), yet I am still in my own thinking and in the thinking of those who have known me since then, a redhead.

Answer (score 2):

The distinction which applies, I think, is between redhead and natural redhead.

Red hair has not been as widely valued, for instance, as blonde, which means there isn't as much experience with wannabe gingers. Bad blonde dye jobs have terms such as "bottle blonde" and "bleached blonde", but I don't think there is much precedent for a simple, one-word distinction between being born redheaded and acquiring it via artifice.

Being redheaded (as in carrot-top, which I was until I hit puberty) is usually accompanied by freckles, but I've seen children with red hair who were simply pale. Since I've seen similarly pale blondes, I don't think that it is possible in principle to tell the difference between a born redhead and the alternatives simply by appearance. This is especially true since there is no (to my knowledge) official standard for redheadedness. Dark hair with distinct red highlights is often called red.

Comment: Just personal observation...  I don't think I have ever seen anyone that dyed their hair a natural red color (but then again, how would I know...).  If the person happens to have fair skin and they add natural red highlights to already-blonde hair, I guess they could fool someone, but normally you can tell if someone has natural red hair.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a Redhead, and so is my wife and kids...

Redhead is different than "blonde" or "brunette" because, as you hinted, it also carries the assumption that the person will have a fair complexion, and probably some degree of freckles.  If you say someone is blonde, that is only a hair color - you can't really assume anything else about them.

I believe that the term redhead is closer to an ethnicity than just hair color in that sense.  You can argue that redhead is only a hair color and "true redhead" implies the other features, but "colloquially", redhead is about more than just hair.

Of course I may be biased...

Comment: Also often marked as having a particular temperament, so more than an ethnicity...culturally various? as for hispanic redheads, maybe...anyway, I upvoted for the thoughtfulness, not because I share your bias (which I do).

Comment: Sounds good, but it doesn't directly address the OP. Can 'redhead' be applied to someone who has red hair even if it has been died to look that way? (note that many people with naturally red hair -don't- have all the those other attributes).

Comment: @Mitch, I thought that was implied, but I guess I should have been more specific.  I don't think that "redhead" can be used for someone with obviously dyed red hair.

Answer (score 1):

The term "red head" is not as common as what I usually hear, which is ginger. The slang is most likely different depending on the culture. One does usually associate a fair skin and perhaps freckles with a person with red hair but as Miss Clairol advertises, "Only her hairdresser knows for sure." Well, that and anyone who knows her intimately.

Usually "red head" or "ginger" is not enough distinction as people will also include "natural" or "true" so in that case, "red head" would be associated with the color of the hair if no more distinction is given. It would be no different than if the person was a brunette.

Blonde also requires distinction. A blonde is a person with blonde hair but there are also shades, like strawberry blonde, dirty blonde, etc. And to add more slang there is the California blonde, which implies the person is not a natural blonde, but a brunette who needs a touch up, usually a major touch up because there is usually as much brown as their is blonde showing. People can even request a California blonde look.

Again, this goes to culture. Since "red head" is slang, it doesn't appear there is an original distinction other than the color of the person's hair, natural or not.

Comment: "Well, that and anyone who knows her intimately." Umm. You do understand, I hope, that hair dye works on _all_ hair?

Comment: Touché - while I've never known anyone to color (dye) all hair, when you're right, you're right.